# how to stop started program after ssh connection is disconnected

Tags: bash, ssh, kill, disconnect

I control two Raspberry Pis via a third one via a ssh connection and started a program on each of them. One program is called collpre, the other one test. It s working great so far, but I figured out, that the started programms are still running after I disconnected the ssh tunnel.

Has anybody an idea how I can make sure, that the started programs are killed, as soon as the ssh connection is disconnected?

Here my bash code. I would like to do it in two separate xterm terminals, as those programs print out some data, which is need to observe.

```
#!usr/bin/bash -f

xterm -title "Pi1" -hold -e ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/key_rsa "pi@192.168.0.107" "python3 collpre.py" &

xterm -title "Pi2" -hold -e ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/key_rsa "pi@192.168.0.108" "python3 test.py"
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: how did you disconnect the ssh?

Comment: just by pressing „ctrl + c“. Is there a „cleaner“ way?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `-t` to the `ssh` command.

Without `-t`, `ssh user@host command` will not allocate a pty on the remote side. And CTRL-C will only kill (`SIGINT`) the local ssh command.

`ssh -t user@host command` will allocate a pty on the remote side and run the command on that pty. For this case, ssh will pass CTRL-C to remote pty which will cause `SIGINT` to be sent to the remote command and kill it.

You can verify like this:

```
$ ssh user@host sleep 123
  <-- Press Ctrl-C and sleep will continue running

$ ssh -t user@host sleep 321
  <-- Press Ctrl-C and sleep will be killed
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/463366/does-getting-disconnected-from-an-ssh-session-kill-your-programs) about SSH sessions and the life time of daemons.

As to your issue, they should be killed, eventually... but this behavior is dependent on your SSH implementation. According to xterm documentation you can exit using Ctrl + d, this will close the terminal window. It is possible that Ctrl + c is killing xterm but ssh sessions may not realize the session has ended right away.

If you want to guarantee a process survives you can use `screen`.